# Group Policy Confilcts

Tags: group-policy

So Recently I have been given the task of learning and getting ready to manage Group Policy for our network. I keep running into the problem of how to detect and report Group Policy conflicts. How would I go about finding and reporting the group policy conflicts on our network?

Answer (score 1):

It's a manual task. You need to get a listing of all your GPO and what they apply as settings and double check what GPO apply what, to be sure no conflict happen.

It's a good exercise to do if it's a mess in your GPO to do anyhow.

If you got tasked that, you might have an idea of what can cause conflict too, but I hope for you no technician did any local GPO/settings in any computers as such might cause you problem to find those settings. It's why if you have problematic computer/user, you might start by looking that way with a gpresult /h:result.htm in example and see what apply.

Comment: So there isn't any way to be able to scan automatically to detect the conflicts? Just using gpresult and sifting through manually?

Comment: @csmith Unless a thirdpart got a tool to do that, that I dont know, not from Microsoft itself sadly.